# forma correcta de escapar un script en un echo

Tags: php, javascript

veran no logro escapar correctamente un script dentro de un echo, aqui esta mi codigo pero no logro hacer que funcione, si alguno me pudiera dar un ejemplo

```
echo '
    // Initialize tooltip component
    $(function () {
      $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
    })
    </script>

</html>';
```

Answer (score 0):

podrias intentar asi concatenando

```
 echo '<script>
// Initialize tooltip component
$(function () {
  $("[data-toggle= '."'tooltip'".']").tooltip()
})
</script>
';
```

Answer (score 0):

Una práctica común para insertar fragmentos de HTML en PHP, más si son largos, es utilizar las etiquetas de apertura y cierre de esta forma:

```
<?php
// código PHP
?>
<script>
// Initialize tooltip component
$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
})
</script>
<?php
// resto del código...
```

Esta forma también tienen como ventaja que los IDE reconocen correctamente el HTML y JS y aplican el resaltado de sintaxis a diferencia de si uno utiliza un string escapado.